# use 2 tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Hi all freind, please how can I use 2 TableView ,i use this code but my problem is I have the same name for cellule

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
       if (choix==1) {
            NSLog(@"%d",choix);
           return [mutable3 count]; 

       }
        else {
                NSLog(@"%d",choix);
            return [mutable2 count];    
        }
    }


    // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (choix==1) {
            NSLog(@"cc%d",choix);
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            }
            cell.textLabel.text = [mutable3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            // Configure the cell...

            return cell;

        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"vvv%d",choix);

            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            }
            cell.textLabel.text = [mutable2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            // Configure the cell...

            return cell;
        }
    }   
    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Table view delegate

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (choix==1) {

                NSLog(@"%d",choix);


        langue.text  =[mutable3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];   

            langView.hidden=TRUE;
        }
        else {

                NSLog(@"%d",choix);
            compain.text =[mutable2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];   

            langView.hidden=TRUE;
        }
   }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: i want use 2 UITableView in the same view

Comment: i have 2 UITextFiled when i clid in my textfiled i show my table view if i click in other textFiled i show the other tableview

Comment: D'abord, pouvez-vous nous dire le sens de «choix» ? Où est-il déclaré ? Pouvez-vous montrer le code ? Montrez le en dessus, dans votre question initiale, avec le formatage, SVP

Comment: Aussi, vous devez augmenter votre taux d'acceptation, si vous voulez que les gens faire des réponses.

Answer (score 1):

Ok its going to be a simple explanation, hope you understand. If you dont please ask and I will elaborate.

TableView Decleration Example:

```
UITableView tableView1;
UITableView tableView2;
```

Each tableview has a variable name which it links to that differs. Because we are working with pointers it allows us to do the following in the delegate methods(All of them, this is only one example)

Delegate Method Example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView== tableView1)
    {
         return 2;
    }
    else if(tableView== tableView2)  //this if statement is not really needed since if you only have 2 table views the second will automatically fall into the else
    {                           
        return 3;
    }
    else  //This else is only needed if you use the second if statement
        return 0;
}
```

And you can use the same approach for all delagate methods

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Comment: i have the same name for cell in the 2 tableview

Comment: What do you mean you have the same name for the cell in the 2 table views, because the cells you can access by using NSIndexPath? So why does the cell have a name?

Comment: What method are you having a problem with?

Comment: because choix have default value diiferent to 1 that why  cell  in the ferst tableview equql the other tqbleview

Comment: if (tableView == self.tablelang) {                                    i do this  for this function           
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Comment: what is choix can you give the devleration, of what type is choix

Comment: @cs1.6 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2667/discussion-between-armand-and-cs1-6)